# Phoenix: how to use values inserted in a template helper in a view function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Suppose I have this template `sample.html.eex`:

```
<div class="<%= @class %>" id="<%= @id %>">
   <a href="home.html" class="<%= @class_a"></a>
</div>
```

Although I want to use all of them in my template I want that `@class` and `@id` come from inserting the values when calling the template and `@class_a` to come from a view function that generates it as the concatenation of `@class` and `@id`. I mean:
1) When I call this template inside other template I pass it these values:

```
<%= render myApp.ComponentView, "sample.html",
    id: "six",
    class: "six" %>
```

2) I have in my component_view a function:

```
def class_a (conn) do
        class+id
end
```

Then, `class_a` is accessible to the template.
My problem is how to get access in my view to `class` and `id` values.
I'm getting several errors while trying to do this. How to do it properly?

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to do. Could you please post an example where you use `class_a`? Or how you would like to use the `class_a` function.

Comment: @Gazler I'll use `@class_a` to apply specific styles. I'll edit my question with a real example.

Comment: You have provided a ton of code. However, I am still not sure what you are actually trying to do. You want a function `class_a` which you assign to a variable `@class_a` via assigns which returns `"#{class}#{id}"`?

Comment: @Gazler Yes. And `class`and `id`are passed in the template when inserting it into another template. It seems that I'm not being able to access those values in my view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just pass `@class` and `@id` to your `class_a` function?

```
def class_a(class, id) do
  "#{class}#{id}"
end

class_a(class, id)
```

You can then call this function from your template:

```
<div class="<%= @class %>" id="<%= @id %>">
   <a href="home.html" class="<%= class_a(@class, @id)"></a>
</div>
```

Please remember that using `@` isn't some magic. `@` is the Eex way of using a variable in assigns. If you have a function `class_a` on your view then you will call it with `class_a`. The only way for `@class_a` to exist would be to add it to `assigns` on your `conn` struct.

If you want a function that takes a single conn you can use `conn.assigns` to get the values:

```
def class_a(conn) do
  class = conn.assigns.class
  id = conn.assigns.id

  "#{class}#{id}"
end
```

Comment: Yes, my goal is to use the second version so that I can avoid long parameters in my template. But, right now, I'm getting an error in my view: `function class_a/0 undefined`

Comment: @PauloJaneiro You need to pass something through. If you have a `class_a` function with a null arity then you can't change the output based on `conn`.

Comment: Ok. And to assign `class_a` to `assigns` on my `conn` struct is `assign(conn, :class_a, class_a)`enough?

Comment: You can do it that way. When calling render, the third argument is the assigns http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/3 http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3